# Battery voltage logger? Random shutdowns on Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, shutdown

Is there any direct way (command line) someone could share, to recursively log into a file the voltage level of the battery?

I just bought a new battery for my loyal macbook air (2012). After a few months of usage, it abruptly and randomly shuts off the laptop at 70% or less. Then it starts again as if nothing happened, but it can anytime randomly happen again–it did. With power cord everything is fine.

I'm in contact with the battery manufacturer, they are quite old and reputed IMO (Kingsener), but I would like to gather some more info. Maybe a logger can detect a voltage drop right before it shuts off. This would also prove that the battery is interrupting the supply, instead of some hardware problem at my power management circuit or anything they could claim.

I found this app that seems to draw graphics, but it is paid and I wouldn't like pay in these circumstances. https://www.bresink.com/osx/0BatteryMonitor/Docs-en/pgs/0040-Graphs.html

Any other suggestions on the cause of the problem are welcomed! Reset SMC is done. Winter cold maybe?

Greets,
Domingo

Comment: Sounds like the battery has a bad cell or cells.  Common problem with replacements.

Comment: Marcel Bresink's apps are well made and supported. In your circumstances, the USD5 would seem a small price to pay.

Comment: No doubt his work is worth the price, but not too fair that I spend money to inform a manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Kingsener, but both the 3rd party Apple battery makers who I trust - iFixit & OWC[NewerTech] - recommend a full charge/discharge cycle to 'reset the clock'.

iFixit say

> For optimal performance, calibrate your newly installed battery: Charge it to 100% and keep charging it for at least 2 more hours. Then use your device until it shuts off due to low battery. Finally, charge it uninterrupted to 100%.

From - https://www.ifixit.com/products/macbook-pro-13-unibody-mid-2009-mid-2012-replacement-battery
also a more comprehansive guide at  - https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration

NewerTech have similar instructions & end by saying

> If it seems that your Newer Technology battery doesn't run as long as you believe it should, you may need to repeat Steps 2 & 3 several times (up to 5 times) before the battery will run at full capacity. And please note that we do require these steps to be performed before authorizing a return.

From https://www.newertech.com/tech_support/newerbatteryconditioning.php

Comment: Thank you that's a good hint to keep in mind.