# "the battery's capacity is significantly reduced" But there's only 25% in reduction and only 600 cycles. Is this a bug?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

The original battery hit 2200 cycles. Roughly went from 6 hours to 2-3 hours of battery life.

Then I replaced it myself with another original which was sitting somewhere for years. It started with 95-90%. After 600 cycles, it is at 75% according to CoconutBattery.

Today I got this message "The battery's capacity is significantly reduced...". The system report shows "Service Recommended". I don't think I ever got this message in my life.

This makes no sense. I still get about 5 hours of battery life.

What am I not seeing here? Can there be a chemical problem or something MacBook can detect??

MBP 13 2015

I observed a new weird behavior that happened a few times over the last few months. When I hit play, the system waits a few seconds before the video plays. Restart fixes it. I don't know if this is related to battery, I wouldn't think so. And Chrome seems to get slower and slower over time, especially websites like YouTube.

Comment: Turn on the Activity monitor and observe the CPU usage

Comment: @Ruskes Why? I see nothing unusual

Comment: "Another original battery that was sitting somewhere for years." Time is the enemy! If this is a 2015-era battery, then it is going to be unreliable, at best.

Comment: @benwiggy unreliable how? 5hr is pretty good

Comment: You're consistently getting c. 5 hours of use on an 8+ year-old battery? -- even using Chrome, the least efficient (and least private) browser? That's above expectations. The OS is designed to flag the battery for service when it falls below 80% of original capacity, or 1000 cycles; there may be other more complex criteria. It's up to you whether you do anything about it. A 2015 MBP is out of service at an Apple Store. You may find a local repair shop who can fit a replacement battery; but any spare part is likely to have some age on it.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467223/battery-voltage-logger-random-shutdowns-on-macbook-air

Comment: When you say you replaced the battery with “another original,” do you mean an original Apple battery or another manufacturer? Keep in mind that a 2015 Mac MacBook is nine years old and it’s very unlikely Apple still stocks this item. From where did you buy the battery?

Comment: @Allan from Apple's supplier

Comment: Unlikely.  Apple makes their suppliers sign contracts not to sell “Apple” products independently.

Comment: @Allan did you sign the contract?

Comment: What does that have to do with understanding Apple’s business practices?  Maybe you just say “I don’t know if the battery is genuine or not” snd you stop deflecting?

Comment: Stop your speculation

Answer (score 0):

The alert appears to communicate that the battery is degrading because it's old.

Because it doesn't say there's a danger it's up to you to decide whether to replace it. There are other possible versions of this alert that will communicate more pressing issues.

Comment: "because it's old" how can we confirm that?

Comment: Well, batteries lose capacity as a result of age (time) and usage (cycle count). The battery capacity is measurable by the system. The alert you're seeing, based on the phrasing, refers to when it drops substantially. 80% is the warrantied threshold (if you have an active warranty) so it's unsurprising the system alerts when it's that low.

Comment: Nah that's not how it works in practice

Comment: @user3722246 If you're sure your battery is fine, what exactly is your question?